# jQuery Ajax request with JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a php file that supllies a JSON to the front end

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: application/json');
require_once('includes/social-parser.php');

$id = $_POST['id'];
$youtube_playlists = $_POST['y'];
$twitter_lists = $_POST['t'];
$keywords = $_POST['k'];

$parser = new socialParser();
$json = $parser->build(json_decode($youtube_playlists), json_decode($twitter_lists), json_decode($keywords),$id);
shuffle($json);

print_r(str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($json)));
die();
?>
```

and in my front end i requst the json using the call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/blog/wp-content/themes/blog/social-ajax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        y: '<?php echo json_encode($youtube_playlists); ?>',
        t: '<?php echo json_encode($twitter_lists); ?>',
        k: '<?php echo json_encode($keywords); ?>',
        id: '<?php echo $post->ID; ?>'
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        jQuery.event.trigger({
            type: "social-ajax",
            social_object: data
        });
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Error loading social data");
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

in some cases it works, but in others it logs an error as it goes to the error callback but with a status 200 .. the error is:
[image]

thanks  in advance

Comment: What is the value of `textStatus`in your `error` function?

Comment: the statusText is "OK"

Comment: And `errorThrown` value?

Comment: am not sure what do you mean by the errorThrown value .. i have put a screenshot of the printed xhr object .. i hope it is in there

Comment: `print_r` is *only* used for debugging, not for normal printing, use `echo` instead.  Also, why are you doing `str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($json))`?

Comment: @AhmadAssaf: `errorThrown` is the third parameter in the `error:` function.

Comment: In your `xhr`, your `responseText` starts with `stdClass Object([youtube] => ...`, that's *not* JSON.  That's the result of `print_r`ing the object.  After making the object the way you want it just do `echo json_encode($json);`, don't echo anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you are invalidating your json:

```
print_r(str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($json)));
```

should just be:

```
// if $json is not valid json
echo json_encode($json);
```

or

```
// if $json is already valid json
echo $json;
```

Comment: thank you .. that was the same issue highlighted by @rocket Hazmat and it did the trick .. thanks a lot :)